# How to make sure Tensorflow's backpropagation works?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wrote a custom layer that is part of a neural network and it contains some operations that I am using for the first time such as tf.scan and tf.slice.

I can easily test that the forward pass works and it makes sense, but how do I know that it will still work during the learning, when it has to do backpropagation? Can I safely assume that everything is going to be fine because the results I get make sense in the forward pass?

I was thinking that one possibility might be to create a neural network, replace one or two layers with the custom ones I have just created, train it, and see what happens. However, despite this would take quite a long time, the network may learn in the other layers whereas in my custom layer it may not work well anyway.

In conclusion, is there any way I can see that back-propagation will work well and I won't have any problems during the learning in this layer?

Comment: Probably the "best" way would be to construct a toy model that only includes your custom layer on a small input, compute the gradients on paper and compare them with what you get out of `tf.gradients` (or `GradientTape` depending on your TF version). Alternatively, train a toy model containing only custom layers on a problem it should be able to solve. That way, no other layers can "interfere" and if the model successfully learns the task you might take that as evidence that backprop through your layer works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, almost all TensorFlow ops are differentiable, including ops such as `tf.abs` or `tf.where` and gradient flows correctly through them. TensorFlow has an automatic differentiation engine, that takes any TensorFlow graph and computes derivatives w.r.t. desired variables.

So if your graph is composed of TensorFlow ops I wouldn't worry about the gradients being wrong (if you would post the code of your layer, I could expand further). However, there are still issues like numerical stability which can make otherwise mathematically sound operation still fail in practice (e.g. naive softmax computation, or tf.exp in your graph in general). Apart from that, TensorFlow differentiation should be correct and taken care of, from the user's point of view.

If you still want to examine your gradients by hand, you can compute the derivatives in your graph using `tf.gradients` op, which will get you the gradients that you wish and you can check by hand if TensorFlow did the differentiation correctly. (See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients)